# Enable AMD/Intel hybrid graphics in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics, opencl

I got **HP-ProBook 450 G0** laptop and it contains flowing graphic cards,
results of `lspci | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
```

As it says Ubuntu 16.04 has problem with fglrx driver, therefore I installed **AMDGPU-Pro Driver**. Even it was installed, seems like it is not working properly. When I navigate to 'Additional Drivers' section in Ubuntu there is nothing with AMD. I did this because system is very slow compared with other machines, and it is mentioned that this is because not having proper graphic drivers in hybrid systems.

As I found, one solution for this Driver problem is updating linux kernel to latest stable release.

How can I solve this graphic issue and speedup the system. Or is it okay to update the kernel?
Also I want to try OpenCL programming with AMD GPU, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `amdgpu -pro` with the `--px` option.

```
amdgpu-pro-install --px
```

To switch graphics you can use the script.

```
/opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
```

The usage will be displayed.

To switch to dGPU run

```
sudo amdgpu-pro-px --mode performance
```