# amdgpu-pro hybrid graphics 16.04.03 windrvr startup problem

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics, amdgpu

I managed to install the new 17.30 version of the amdgpu-pro driver for ubuntu 16.04.03 using the --px flag as described here: 
*[Enable AMD/Intel hybrid graphics in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893954/enable-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-in-ubuntu-16-04)*

As long as I run the driver in powersaving mode, everything works fine.
If I change to performance mode which should use the ATI card in addition to the Intel chip and do a logout I am unable to log in in GUI mode again.

The error showing up before the login screen shows again is:

*Module windrvr1200 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-96-generic*

Can anyone help me? I have to admit i don't understand this error at all.

I am using a HP laptop with hybrid AMD/Intel graphics and my card us supposed to be supported by the driver

PS: Both cards are well recognized:

*00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal PRO [Radeon R7 M260] (rev ff)*

Comment: I admit this is actually an odd error. If nobody answer, you could ask on IRC channel `#radeon` of Freenode server. On side note, are you sure you want AMDGPU-Pro? AMD is focused on radeonsi driver, and [the current radeonsi is much-much faster](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amdgpu-1730-radeonsi&num=1). The only reason AMDGPU-Pro is around is because of some corporate software requiring compatibility OpenGL profiles, and Mesa drivers doesn't support them *(well, not higher than 3.0 anyway)*.

Comment: typing 'man radeon'  does not list my card (radeon r7 m260). As far as i understand radeonsi is the same as amdgpu which is  the open source driver. So it seems my card is not supported. 
Thanks for the irc channel tip

Comment: 1. Manual could just be missing a card. Take a look at `glxinfo | grep renderer` *(possibly with `DRI_PRIME=1` set to use the Radeon instead of Intel)*, and if you see words AMD or Radeon *(I don't know unfortunately the exact wording because my card is older)*, then it is surely supported. Because Mesa have only one driver for R7, which is radeonsi. 2. You're confused about namings. AMDGPU is indeed open source, but it's a kernel driver *(whereas radeonsi is its userspace component)*. AMDGPU-Pro on the other hand is a proprietary userspace driver + some not yet mainlined patches for AMDGPU.

Comment: So I got the recent Mesa and it seems my card is supported.

*glxinfo | grep OpenGL 
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) 

DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL 
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD OLAND (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-96-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)*

Comment: I can start an application with DRI_Prime=1 now,                                          xrandr --listproviders gives
*Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x6e cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 9 associated providers: 2 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x41 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:OLAND @ pci:0000:04:00.0
Provider 2: id: 0x41 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:OLAND @ pci:0000:04:00.0*                I guess that means with DRI_Prime I use the ATI card

Comment: Yes, you can use AMD with DRI_PRIME. FTR it's good to know [the distinction between using export and assigning a variable directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158231/2388257).